# Xcode playground not executing functions

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground

I created a new playground and I add simple function but the function is never been call:

```
var str = "New playground"

func hello()
{
    print("Hello, World")
}
```

[image]

Any of you knows why the function is not been call ?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because you didn't call the function. Just call it:

```
func hello()
{
    print("Hello, World")
}

hello()
```

Comment: I add it the line with hello() but I get the error : Use of unresolved identifier 'hello'

Comment: Note: The function needs to be declared before its call, like this example is written.

Comment: not working       
Expected '{' in body of function declaration

Answer (score 1):

Also, If you are calling the method before its implementation, the Swift Playground wouldn't allow you to do that, and errors out as below

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'hello'
```

**WRONG ORDER:**

```
hello()
func hello()
{
    print("Hello, World")
}
```

**RIGHT ORDER**

```
func hello()
{
    print("Hello, World")
}
hello()
```

Comment: Expected '{' in body of function declaration